# Google Map activity - network connection required

Tags: android, google-maps, android-alertdialog

I am new in Android programming and I have a program with a public class like this: public class MyLocationActivity extends MapActivity which shows my location on google maps. I would like to add an alert message like "network connection is required" and for example open the wifi when the mobile is not connected on the internet. I tried many things but I didn't manage to get it work. How can I display such a message in a map activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the WiFi options screen with the following code:

```
private void showWifiOptions(){  
        Intent wifiOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
                android.provider.Settings.android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(wifiOptionsIntent);  
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this private void inside the public class? Because eclipse shows me an error: "this method is never used locally"

Comment: Yes it is meant to be put into a class. Then you can call showWifiOptions() when you need to. You get that warning in Eclipse because ... you don't actually call that method from anywhere.